# SQLite INDEXES in System.Data.SQLite vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sqlite

this is my first time of using SQLite - INDEXES. I have a big database with 1 million records. I read that using an index is faster but I feel no difference. Here's the steps I followed.

1. Creation of index for table AllData (FileTitle, FileAuthor, FileLanguage, PublicationYear, Publisher, FileType, ISBN, Description, FileURL, FilePath, CatID,FileMD5) with a tool "SQLite Administrator".
2. While creating the index I selected all the columns to be indexed. It increased the size of database from 450 MB to 1.27 GB
3. I used "Select * From ALLData Where CattID='5' Limit 25000" statement to get results.

But I found no difference in speed after indexing. I read that there is no special thing to do while executing a query because SQLite engine auto use indexes. But I found no difference in speed.

Please guide me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause is using the field `CatId`.  That needs to be the first column in the index:  `AllData(CatId, FileTitle, FileAuthor, FileLanguage, PublicationYear, Publisher, FileType, ISBN, Description, FileURL, FilePath, FileMD5)`.

Comment: But I am not searching just only from CatId. Most of the time I search from FileTitle,CatId and FileAuthor. What I have to do to make my query faster for that?

Comment: @user934820 . . . You would have to create separate indexes for different queries.

Comment: Call me stupid but will you please guide me to any tutorial for that?

Comment: @user934820 . . . MySQL actually has a good description in the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Yes now it is fast. But while executing "SELECT * FROM Alldata where FileTitle MATCH 'text here' limit 20000" generates a sql logical error. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should read this excellent answer by Bill Karwin as well: [finding the optimal order of multi-column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438065/finding-the-optimal-order-of-multi-column-index/19439433#19439433) it is really easy to understand and apply.